# Get indexPath for at Point when scrolling tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to get the cell on which I pressed when I preview (UIViewControllerPreviewing), the problem is that the location that returns the method is on the view and not on the actual position of the cell when scrolling in the tableview. I'm trying this:

```
func previewingContext(_ previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {
let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "TaskDetail", bundle: nil)

guard let detailViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailTaskViewController") as? DetailTaskViewController else { return nil }

guard let indexPath = self.listTasksUITableView.indexPathForRow(at: location) else { return nil }
                print(indexPath.row)
}
```

This would return an indexpath of eg 2, when I actually scroll to row 18

Comment: `UIView.convertPoint(_:fromView:)`

Comment: Not get exactly position because the tableview is scrolling , conver to point get point from view , not detected the position when scrolling for tableview

Answer (score 1):

As @Sulthan notes in the comments, you need to convert the coordinate to the 'local' coordinate system of `listTasksUITableView` with the [`UIView` instance method `convert(_:from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622424-convertpoint).

Put this line*

```
let convertedLocation = listTasksUITableView.convert(location, from: self)
```

before

```
guard let indexPath = ...
```

and use `convertedLocation` in that line instead of `location`.

I needed a similar trick for a Xamarin project where I was manually calculating coordinates (similar to `location.Y - tableView.Y`) and that failed when the view was scrolled. This way of converting does apply scrolling into account.

*: my Swift is too rusty to tell me whether to put `guard`, `!` etc. there. I always rely on the compiler to tell me that.